# How to update nsswitch to use the second DNS server too if there is an NXDOMAIN?

Tags: resolv.conf, nsswitch

The resolv.conf looks like this:

```
machine:~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
search  foo.bar
nameserver      DNSSERVERIP1
nameserver      DNSSERVERIP2
machine:~ #
```

The first DNSSERVERIP1 doesn't know about the barfoo.com.

But the second DNS server: DNSSERVERIP2 knows it. Resolves good.

I know that by default if the first DNS server returns NXDOMAIN, then the second DNS server will not be asked.

But the Question: How do I configure /etc/nsswitch.conf so if an NXDOMAIN happens for the first DNS server, the second will asked?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with `nsswitch.conf`.
This file specifies the data sources to use for each categories. It is not meant to "influence" the way each source works (in your case, use another DNS server if the first answer doesn't please you).

You could try with the `[STATUS=ACTION]` to modify the behavior following a result obtained from the preceding data source. But this is not what you want because you don't want to change your data source (dns).

You said it yourself: if DNSSERVERIP1 doesn't know the answer (NXDOMAIN), it means the server is authoritative to answer that. So the answer is final (regarding the DNS specification) and there is no point querying another server. Again, this is by definition and you can't override it.

The only way is to make this work is by making sure your DNS setup is consistent: if DNSSERVERIP1 and DNSSERVERIP2 are meant to be clones, then do so. If DNSSERVERIP2 has the answer, DNSSERVERIP1 shall also have it.